# Sybase commenting

Tags: sql, sybase

I want to comment on multiple columns in a table to describe each column, so is there any specific query to comment all columns in table in a single query. I am using sybase 16.

Answer (score 0):

Sybase ASE does not have a COMMENT-type statement.